# SQL-how to bring the value of first row to the second row

Tags: sql

I have a table with following values:

```
week_no     amt   amt_diff
1           500    100
2           600    300
3           900    100
4          1000   null
```

When I subtract `week2.amt-week1.amt` the difference is getting saved in the `amt_diff` column of `week_no=1`. But I want the result to be stored with the `week_no=2` record.

Can anyone help me with the SQL?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work.  You can make it a `SELECT` first to make sure you get the desired results.  The syntax is valid in SQL Server, not sure about other RDBMS.

```
UPDATE m2 
SET amt_diff = (m2.amt-m1.amt)
FROM MyTable m2
INNER JOIN MyTable m1
  ON m1.week_no = (M2.week_no - 1)
```

It will update all records that have week after it to be calculated.

To just select the values:

```
SELECT amt_diff = (m2.amt-m1.amt)
FROM MyTable m2
INNER JOIN MyTable m1
  ON m1.week_no = (M2.week_no - 1)
```

Comment: But i got this value by joining some 5 tables then how can i get the value for week2-week1 in week2 row

Comment: @ResKing that doesn't make any sense.  What do you need?

Comment: the query u have given is to update the table rite??? but i want to display the values alone without updating the table

Comment: @ResKing added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE YOURTABLE T
 SET    T.AMT_DIFF = ( T.AMT - NVL(( SELECT TT.AMT 
                                     FROM   YOURTABLE TT 
                                     WHERE  TT.WEEK_NO = (T.WEEK_NO - 1)
                                   )
                                   ,0)
                     )
 WHERE T.WEEK_NO = 2;
```

Might work for you.

Comment: @JNK May I Google that for You? Ok, kidding. AFAIK the answer is yes. If someone wants an RDBMS independent solution, she might go with `COALESCE(...)` which is ANSI standard.

Comment: I did google it and only got hits for oracle.  That's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
update k
set k.amt_diff=(select k2.amt from week k2 where week_no=k.week_no+1)-amt
from week k
```